# Detect if Assistive Touch is On

Tags: ios, assistive

I have to detect functional HOME buttons and LOCK screen buttons which I have been able to do

But the issue is user can emulate these buttons' behaviour if assistive touch is on. So is there a way in IOS to detect if user has Assistive Touch turned on so that app can ask them to turn it off before moving on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apple hasn't provided any official APIs for that either accessing the existing Assistive Touch feature.